# Remove ?ver= from wp_register_script

Tags: wp-register-script

I'm getting nags on google speed test regarding the querystrings in my scripts. So, I'm trying to remove them by passing false as the argument for that parameter. However, it does not seem to have effect:

```
wp_register_script('myscript', get_bloginfo('template_directory').'/scripts.myversionnumber.js',false,false,true);
wp_enqueue_script('myscript');
```

PS: the "myversionnumber" part of the js filename is my means of controlling cache/versioning rather than the ?ver= approach which apparently trips up some proxy servers (according to Google pagespeed test):

> **Remove query strings from static resources** Enabling public caching in
>   the HTTP headers for static resources allows the browser to download
>   resources from a nearby proxy server rather than from a remote origin
>   server. Learn more
>
> **Suggestions for this page**
>
> Resources with a "?" in the URL are not cached by some proxy caching
>   servers. Remove the query string and encode the parameters into the
>   URL for the following resources:

Comment: Interesting question, never knew that query strings would trip up page speed. While I don't have a solution, lemme comment on setting the parameter to "false": Afaik, you either enter a version number, or it defaults to the current wordpress version.

Comment: I thought that the script would be cached, even with a version number - and that altering the version number would 'break' the cache, purposefully so that the new, rather than old, script would be loaded....

Comment: @Stephen, that's the idea exactly. However, apparently some proxy cache servers will not cache resource URLs with querystring params. That's why I'm opting to encode the params in the filename instead. Same effect, less baggage.

Comment: Hello Scott B. I am facing the same problem. After I run a test on gtmetrix I am getting errors for the query. Did the solution provided by @SickHippie work for you? Is it safe to use it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you have to pass NULL as the 4th parameter.

```
wp_register_script(
    'myscript',
    get_bloginfo('template_directory').'/scripts.myversionnumber.js',
    false,
    NULL,
    true);
wp_enqueue_script('myscript');
```

Answer (score 3):

You can pass `null` as the version value to `wp_register_script` or `wp_enqueue_script` and it should drop the query string.

```
<?php
wp_enqueue_script(
   'myscript',
   '/path/to/script.js',
   array(),
   null
);
```

Answer (score 3):

### Foreword

I solved this a lot differently from *SickHippie* and *chrisguitarguy* and I guess it's not the way it is supposed to be solved, but it's working really good for me.

### The code...

I put this snippet of code at the end of my theme's `functions.php` file:

```
function remove_cssjs_querystring( $src ) {
  if( strpos( $src, '?rev=' ) ) // copy/paste this line and the next one to take away what you want from the end of your css/js
    $src = remove_query_arg( 'rev', $src );
  if( strpos( $src, 'ver=' ) )
    $src = remove_query_arg( 'ver', $src );
  return $src;
}
add_filter( 'style_loader_src', 'remove_cssjs_querystring', 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'script_loader_src', 'remove_cssjs_querystring', 10, 2 );
```

### Where the idea came from...

I was loooking for it on Google and I found [this article](http://www.vionblog.com/remove-query-string-from-wordpress-css-js-files/), but  I kept having a problem with css/js: at this point my code still had (here and there) at the end something like `.../some-stylesheet.css?rev=...` and I thought about extending the code snippet a little bit to include anything that could have been after `.css`.